# VSCode build not working - No build task defined. Mark a task with 'isBuildCommand' in the tasks.json file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have fresh install of VSCode, and this tiny basic TypeScript app.

First time, when I want to build the app, VScode needs to generate tasks.json.

And it worked long time ago before.

Today I am getting this weird message

> No build task defined. Mark a task with 'isBuildCommand' in the tasks.json file.

I don't remember seeing this message before.

[image]

But, OK, I click **Configure Build Task**, select TypeScript task, and tasks.json gets generated.

[image]

But, what happens, after I try to build now, Ctrl+Shift+B, and **I get the exact same message again**

[image]

**Any ideas? Thanks.**

BTW, adding this setting to tasks.json doesnt solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Also started seeing this today after updating to 1.11.2, using Gulp in my case. The URL in `tasks.json` shows a [different structure for `isBuildCommand`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_mapping-gulp-grunt-and-jake-output-to-problem-matchers) but that still doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This issue was also adressed here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24796

It says:

> Closing and reopening the window (without starting Code) resolves this issue.

Comment: I tried closing and reopening the window, didnt work this morning, but checked again 2 hours later, now it works !! VSCode works in mysterious ways ;))

Answer (score 6):

> Closing and reopening the window

*Which* window?  Closing and reopening the tasks.json window didn't work for me (in VS Code 1.11.2).

Here's what did though:

- Closing and re-opening *Visual Studio Code*
- Ctrl-Shift-B (or your build shortcut)

Comment: Close the Visual Studio Code window (yes, the editor itself), and restart it.

Comment: Are you sure? I think he may have meant ["Reload Window"](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3592#issuecomment-191162327) `Ctr`+`Shift`+`P` and type `Reload W...` and you'll see it?

Answer (score 3):

> [As of 18th September 2021] and VS Code version: `1.60.0`

For me, it turned out to be that I wasn't having `"isBuildCommand": true`.

I understand that this post already assumes that `isBuildCommand` is already included. But VS Code didn't include this by default for me and being new to VS code if I reached this page, it might be helpful to someone else who is new.

I wanted to have two configurations - `Debug` and `Release`. This is how my two configs looks -

```
{
    "label": "build Debug",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "type": "process",
    "isBuildCommand": true,
    "args": [
        "build",
        "${workspaceFolder}/ABCD/ABCD.csproj",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
    ],
    "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
},
{
    "label": "build Release",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "type": "process",
    "isBuildCommand": true,
    "args": [
        "build",
        "${workspaceFolder}/ABCD/ABCD.csproj",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary",
        "-c",
        "Release"
    ],
    "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
}
```

Comment: I actually wasn't looking for build tasks but for test tasks. But the answer was actually the same, use "isTestCommand: true" for a test and it works like isBuildCommand for a build.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my `tasks.json` had some nonsense in it. Instead of the "command" property, I wrongly named it "executable"...*

So consider if:

1. Your JSON is valid [syntactically](https://jsonlint.com/) (see screenshot below)
2. Your JSON is valid [according to what VS Code expects](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

*Syntactically invalid:*
[image: syntactically invalid JSON (for example with a property, followed by a colon, but no value... will cause this issue]

*Schematically invalid:*[image: even if JSON is syntactically valid, it may not meet the expectations for the schema of tasks.json]

And while I think the other answers are probably correct (I can't reproduce so I can't verify; [the issue has been fixed...](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24796)), I think when the comment said ...

> Closing and reopening the window (without starting Code)

... it may have meant the [`Reload Window` command.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3592#issuecomment-191162327)

---

*I wrongly named the `tasks.json` property "executable", vs "command" because...

1. I thought "command" was causing issues (*it wasn't*)
2. I wanted to run a specific executable in a specific directory like "C:/somewhere/python.exe"; (*"command" can do that*).

I don't know why I thought "executable" was valid! I thought I was referencing some example, but can't find it... :) )

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I put the tasks.json file in a new .vscode folder next to the file I wanted to build.

- My folder >

  - myFile
  - .vscode >

    - tasks.json
  - tasks.json (this file has no effect)

The funny thing is, My folder was already named .vscode in my case. I guess it has to be a sub-layer.

Answer (score 0):

I had errors even after checking task.json. Turned out to be that there was an error in IntelliSense Configurations - Compiler path...

[image: IntelliSense Configurations settings]

Not sure if this would help, but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that after installing some extensions (cmake or java) my files like launch.json, settings.json, c_cpp_properties.json and tasks.json were changed occasionally

I stirred up these changes and deleted some useless extensions and reloaded vscode
After that it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue after installing the new VS Code.

I resolve it by:

First, you have to initialize the typescript by this command on your folder dir

```
tsc --init
```

then you'll automatically get the option to build tsc: watch -tsconfig.json & tsc: build -tsconfig.json