# Release build in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

When building my C# project, how can I switch to Release configuration in VS Code?

Right now I launch my application with `Ctrl+F5` or `Debug -> Start Without Debugging` which also builds it, but this creates only a debug build at `bin/Debug`. There is no `Build` menu in VS Code.

Here's my tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/dotnetcore-test.csproj"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Edit the [tasks.json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34268034/492336) like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build Debug",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/dotnetcore-test.csproj"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "taskName": "build Release",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/dotnetcore-test.csproj",
                "-c",
                "Release"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }        
    ]
}
```

then when you press `Ctrl+Shift+B` the `Command Palette` will let you choose between `Build Release` and `Build Debug`

source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x

Comment: I can see the permutations quickly getting out of hand. Maybe some config variables could be used instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303316/vscode-defining-own-variables-in-tasks-json

Comment: As of 18th Sept, 2021 and VS Code: 1.60.0. I had the same issue and it turned out to be I wasn't having `"isBuildCommand": true` in both configs due to which I got an error `No build tasks defined`. Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69232604/4317232

Comment: Really clear answer. Its that , "-c", "Release"   bit that does it for me, cheers.

Answer (score 16):

You can perform a release build via the terminal with:

```
dotnet build -c release
```

If you want to run in release, use:

```
dotnet run -c release
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build

Answer (score 3):

you can just do that without tasks.json , but with Launch.json

Here is a configuration I always use to build my C# projects by F5 :
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/parsalotfy/10a466c0681fc14bdd86debee7e9789d)

Answer (score 1):

**Terminal** -> **Run Task...** -> select the task name to run